# STM32G0 bootloader memory expansion problem

Tags: c, memory-management, stm32, bootloader

I've a running C application on STM32G0,
it uses a bootloader but its size is almost 99.8% of all space available,
this is the configuration of Bootloader Memory:

```
//Bootloader OK Loader script:
MEMORY
{
   RAM    (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 36K
   FLASH    (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 10K
   BOOT_CFG    (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x8002800,   LENGTH = 2K
   OTP     (r)          : ORIGIN = 0x8003000,   LENGTH = 2K
   PROG    (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8003800,   LENGTH = 114K
}
```

and this is the configuration of application memory:

```
//Application OK Loader script:
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 36K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8003800,   LENGTH = 112K
  INNER_REG (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x801F800,   LENGTH = 2K
}
```

I need more space for bootloader so I've created a different loader script for both:

```
//Bootloader NOT-OK Loader script:
MEMORY
{
   RAM    (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 36K
   FLASH    (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 12K
   BOOT_CFG    (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x8003000,   LENGTH = 2K
   OTP     (r)          : ORIGIN = 0x8003800,   LENGTH = 2K
   PROG    (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8004000,   LENGTH = 110K
}
```

and this is the configuration of application memory:

```
//Application NOT-OK Loader script:
MEMORY
{
    RAM    (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 36K
    FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8004000,   LENGTH = 110K
    INNER_REG (r)    : ORIGIN = 0x801F800,   LENGTH = 2K
}
```

The new bigger bootloader seems to be ok, and also the application starts without problem,
but after a while there's an exception somewhere and I can't understand the reason:

[image: Exception]

Any idea about how I can discover and solve the problem?
Following are the full loader for bigger space bootloader:

```
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file      LinkerScript.ld
 * @author    Auto-generated by STM32CubeIDE
 * @brief     Linker script for STM32G070RBTx Device from STM32G0 series
 *                      128Kbytes FLASH
 *                      36Kbytes RAM
 *
 *            Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
 *            to application requirements.
 *
 *            Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
 *
 * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
 * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);    /* end of "RAM" Ram type memory */

_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200 ;    /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400 ;   /* required amount of stack */

/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 36K
  FLASH    (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 12K
  BOOT_CFG    (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x8003000,   LENGTH = 2K
  OTP     (r)       : ORIGIN = 0x8003800,   LENGTH = 2K
  PROG    (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8004000,   LENGTH = 110K
}

/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { 
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

    /*CONFIG   */
    .config_block :
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        PROVIDE(_bg_start = .);
        KEEP(*(.boot_config))
        PROVIDE(_bg_end = _bg_start + 0x800);
    
    } >BOOT_CFG

  /* OTP */
  .otp_block :
  {
    PROVIDE(_sotp = .);
    KEEP(*(.device_address))  
    PROVIDE(_eotp = .);   
  } >OTP
  
  /* PROG  */
  .prog_block :
  {
    _sprog = .;
    _eprog = _sprog + 0x1b800;   
  } >PROG

  /* Used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
    
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* Uninitialized data section into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough "RAM" Ram  type memory left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM

  /* Remove information from the compiler libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

and the loader for the corresponding application:

```
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file      LinkerScript.ld
 * @author    Auto-generated by STM32CubeIDE
 * @brief     Linker script for STM32G070KBTx Device from STM32G0 series
 *                      128Kbytes FLASH
 *                      36Kbytes RAM
 *
 *            Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
 *            to application requirements.
 *
 *            Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
 *
 * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
 * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
 * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);    /* end of "RAM" Ram type memory */

_Min_Heap_Size = 0x1000;    /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x1000;   /* required amount of stack */

/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 36K
  //OTP    (r)      : ORIGIN = 0x8003000,   LENGTH = 2K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8004000,   LENGTH = 110K
  INNER_REG (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x801F800,   LENGTH = 2K
}

/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { 
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* OTP */
  /*.otp_block 0x8003000:         */        
  /*{                             */
  /* . = ALIGN(4);                */
  /*    _sotp = ABSOLUTE(.) ;     */
  /*  KEEP(*(.device_address))    */
  /*   . = ALIGN(4);              */
  /*   _eotp = ABSOLUTE(.) ;      */
  /*}                             */
  
  _device_addres_pos = 0x8003800;
  
  

  /* INNER_REG */
  .registro_block (NOLOAD) :
  {
    _ri_start = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
   . = ALIGN(8);

    KEEP(*(.registro_interno))
     . = ALIGN(8); 
    _ri_stop = ABSOLUTE(.) ;   
  } >INNER_REG



  /* Used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
    
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* Uninitialized data section into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough "RAM" Ram  type memory left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM





  /* Remove information from the compiler libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

this is how I pass from bootloader to application:

```
void flash_jump_to_app(void)
{
  /* Function pointer to the address of the user application. */
  fnc_ptr jump_to_app;
  jump_to_app = (fnc_ptr)(*(volatile uint32_t*) ((&_sprog)+1u));
  /* Change the main stack pointer. */
  __set_MSP(*((volatile uint32_t*)(&_sprog)));
  jump_to_app();
}
```

whilst the startup file for the application is:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file      startup_stm32g070xx.s
  * @author    MCD Application Team
  * @brief     STM32G070xx devices vector table for SW4STM32 toolchain.
  *            This module performs:
  *                - Set the initial SP
  *                - Set the initial PC == Reset_Handler,
  *                - Set the vector table entries with the exceptions ISR address
  *                - Branches to main in the C library (which eventually
  *                  calls main()).
  *            After Reset the Cortex-M0+ processor is in Thread mode,
  *            priority is Privileged, and the Stack is set to Main.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2018 STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the 
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

  .syntax unified
  .cpu cortex-m0
  .fpu softvfp
  .thumb

.global g_pfnVectors
.global Default_Handler

/* start address for the initialization values of the .data section.
defined in linker script */
.word _sidata
/* start address for the .data section. defined in linker script */
.word _sdata
/* end address for the .data section. defined in linker script */
.word _edata
/* start address for the .bss section. defined in linker script */
.word _sbss
/* end address for the .bss section. defined in linker script */
.word _ebss

  .section .text.Reset_Handler
  .weak Reset_Handler
  .type Reset_Handler, %function
Reset_Handler:
  ldr   r0, =_estack
  mov   sp, r0          /* set stack pointer */

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */
  movs r1, #0
  b LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr r3, =_sidata
  ldr r3, [r3, r1]
  str r3, [r0, r1]
  adds r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr r0, =_sdata
  ldr r3, =_edata
  adds r2, r0, r1
  cmp r2, r3
  bcc CopyDataInit
  ldr r2, =_sbss
  b LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */
FillZerobss:
  movs r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2]
  adds r2, r2, #4


LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr r3, = _ebss
  cmp r2, r3
  bcc FillZerobss

/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
  bl  SystemInit
/* Call static constructors */
  bl __libc_init_array
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
  bl app_main

LoopForever:
    b LoopForever


.size Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler

/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an
 *         unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving
 *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
 *
 * @param  None
 * @retval : None
*/
    .section .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
  b Infinite_Loop
  .size Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
/******************************************************************************
*
* The minimal vector table for a Cortex M0.  Note that the proper constructs
* must be placed on this to ensure that it ends up at physical address
* 0x0000.0000.
*
******************************************************************************/
   .section .isr_vector,"a",%progbits
  .type g_pfnVectors, %object
  .size g_pfnVectors, .-g_pfnVectors


g_pfnVectors:
  .word  _estack
  .word  Reset_Handler
  .word  NMI_Handler
  .word  HardFault_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  SVC_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  PendSV_Handler
  .word  SysTick_Handler
  .word  WWDG_IRQHandler                   /* Window WatchDog              */
  .word  0                                 /* reserved                     */
  .word  RTC_TAMP_IRQHandler               /* RTC through the EXTI line    */
  .word  FLASH_IRQHandler                  /* FLASH                        */
  .word  RCC_IRQHandler                    /* RCC                          */
  .word  EXTI0_1_IRQHandler                /* EXTI Line 0 and 1            */
  .word  EXTI2_3_IRQHandler                /* EXTI Line 2 and 3            */
  .word  EXTI4_15_IRQHandler               /* EXTI Line 4 to 15            */
  .word  0                                 /* reserved                     */
  .word  DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler          /* DMA1 Channel 1               */
  .word  DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler        /* DMA1 Channel 2 and Channel 3 */
  .word  DMA1_Ch4_7_DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQHandler /* DMA1 Channel 4 to Channel 7, DMAMUX1 overrun */
  .word  ADC1_IRQHandler                   /* ADC1                         */
  .word  TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler    /* TIM1 Break, Update, Trigger and Commutation */
  .word  TIM1_CC_IRQHandler                /* TIM1 Capture Compare         */
  .word  0                                 /* reserved                     */
  .word  TIM3_IRQHandler                   /* TIM3                         */
  .word  TIM6_IRQHandler                   /* TIM6                         */
  .word  TIM7_IRQHandler                   /* TIM7                         */
  .word  TIM14_IRQHandler                  /* TIM14                        */
  .word  TIM15_IRQHandler                  /* TIM15                        */
  .word  TIM16_IRQHandler                  /* TIM16                        */
  .word  TIM17_IRQHandler                  /* TIM17                        */
  .word  I2C1_IRQHandler                   /* I2C1                         */
  .word  I2C2_IRQHandler                   /* I2C2                         */
  .word  SPI1_IRQHandler                   /* SPI1                         */
  .word  SPI2_IRQHandler                   /* SPI2                         */
  .word  USART1_IRQHandler                 /* USART1                       */
  .word  USART2_IRQHandler                 /* USART2                       */
  .word  USART3_4_IRQHandler               /* USART3, USART4               */

/*******************************************************************************
*
* Provide weak aliases for each Exception handler to the Default_Handler.
* As they are weak aliases, any function with the same name will override
* this definition.
*
*******************************************************************************/

  .weak      NMI_Handler
  .thumb_set NMI_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak      HardFault_Handler
  .thumb_set HardFault_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak      SVC_Handler
  .thumb_set SVC_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak      PendSV_Handler
  .thumb_set PendSV_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak      SysTick_Handler
  .thumb_set SysTick_Handler,Default_Handler

  .weak      WWDG_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set WWDG_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      RTC_TAMP_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set RTC_TAMP_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      FLASH_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set FLASH_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      RCC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set RCC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      EXTI0_1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI0_1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      EXTI2_3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI2_3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      EXTI4_15_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set EXTI4_15_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      DMA1_Ch4_7_DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set DMA1_Ch4_7_DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      ADC1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set ADC1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM1_CC_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM3_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM6_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM6_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM7_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM7_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM14_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM14_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM15_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM15_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM16_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM16_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      TIM17_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set TIM17_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      I2C1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set I2C1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      I2C2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set I2C2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      SPI1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set SPI1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      SPI2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set SPI2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      USART1_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set USART1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      USART2_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set USART2_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

  .weak      USART3_4_IRQHandler
  .thumb_set USART3_4_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: When you pass controll to the app do you change the vector table address to 0x8004000? It you use STM startup files did you remove the line which sets the VTOR?

Comment: I've attached the info you required but it seems to be ok from my point of view, in any case I haven't change this code and in the old project it works fine

Comment: it is in system_stmxxxx.c file comment the line SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; and remember to set this register in the bootloader

Comment: you are right, thanks, it was       #define VECT_TAB_OFFSET  0x3800U  in file system_stm32g0xx.c

Comment: BTW bootloader should set it instead of the application startup.